# How Can I make an event after choosing an item on dropdown list with reactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, select, events

actually I'm working on reactJs project with Laravek API. I want to change the value of a field after choosing a item on a dropdown List.
This an exemple : if I choose for example bimothly the value of Contract Rent Per Period Should be 444 (222*2) etc...
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t58vK.png
This is my code:

```
  <Row>
              <Col sm='6' className='mb-1'>
                <Label className='form-label' >Select Period</Label>
                <select className='form-control'>
                  <option>Select Period
                  </option>
                  {periodList.map((item) => {
                    return (<option value='periodicity'>{item.periodicity}</option>
                    )
                  })
                  }
                </select>
                </Col>
                {unit.map((item) =>

                <Col sm='6' className='mb-1'>
                <Label className='form-label'>
                  Contract Rent Per Period
                </Label>
                
               
                  <Input type='text' value={item?.unit_rent_per_month} />
   
           
              </Col>      )}
              <Col sm='6' className='mb-1'>
                <Label className='form-label' for='compl_date'>
                  Date <span className='text-danger'>*</span>
                </Label>
                <Flatpickr
                  className='form-control'
                  value={date}
                  id='date'

                />
              </Col>


                {unit.map((item) =>

                <Col sm='6' className='mb-1'>
                <Label className='form-label'>
                  Contract Rent Per Period
                </Label>
                
               
                  <Input type='text' value={item?.unit_rent_per_month} />
   
           
              </Col>      )}
              
          
            </Row>
```

I would be very thankful if anyone of you can help mee

Answer (score 0):

you can add onClick on your Label and do with them what your want

Comment: I didn't know how to integrate it and make relation between the select and the other field

Comment: I would create an array with objects with values ​​that are in the dropdown list and
 value that should be in integers arr =[{
  value: bimothly,
  input1Value: 444,
  inputValue: 2
}]
and when choosing a new value for select (using onChange), for example, assign the selected object to the state (useState, for example, or to any variable) and assign the value to this variable in input

Comment: all the data is from database not static

Comment: you can create new array which will contain data from the server and you need the format  
const myNewArr = databaseValues.map((value) => {
return {.value: value.value, input1Value: value.input1Value, inputValue: value.inputValue }
})